# Dovecot Proxy with Lua or?

Tags: dovecot

I've build a Dovecot proxy that sends users to specific backends based on their domain. Domain A goes to server A and domain B goes to server B, etc. The list of domains is not static, but it isn't changing a lot. That works totally ok with a passdb driver sql and a simple SQL statement like:

```
password_query = SELECT 
    NULL as password, 
    'y' as nopassword, 
    'y' as proxy, 
    NULL as destuser, 
    'y' as proxy_nopipelining, 
    host, 
    'y' as nodelay, 
    'y' as nologin, 
    'any-cert' as 'starttls' 
  FROM proxy_domain WHERE domain = '%d';
```

The dovecot config contains:

```
passdb {
  args = /etc/dovecot/sql.conf
  driver = sql
}

userdb {
  args = static uid=5000 gid=5000 home=/dev/null
  driver = static
}
```

My "problem" is not really a problem - but... I need to install and run a Mysql/MariaDB server only for this job and I think, there must be an easier way to resolve the host for a specific domain. A parallel postfix installation uses a simple transport map for doing the same job. I don't need a SQL server for that simple lookup.

I thought about the [Dovecot Lua passdb](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/lua_based_authentication/#authentication-lua-based-authentication) or [static passdb](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/authentication/static_password_database/#authentication-static-password-database) but I can't find any useful example to match a domain against a host with Lua or how I return all the necessary parameters?

So I've installed the debian package `dovecot-auth-lua`.

I tried with:

```
passdb {
  driver = lua
  args = file=/etc/dovecot/passdb.lua blocking=yes
  default_fields = password=NULL nopassword=y proxy=y destuser=NULL proxy_nopipelining=y nodelay=y nologin=y starttls=any-cert
}
```

Is blocking here necessary? It's readonly operation, or?

The Lua script:

```
local database = "/etc/dovecot/backends"

function auth_passdb_lookup(req)
 for line in io.lines(database) do
   for domain, host in string.gmatch(line, "(.+)%s(.+)") do
     if (domain == req.domain) then
       return dovecot.auth.PASSDB_RESULT_OK, "host=" .. host
     end
   end
 end
 return dovecot.auth.PASSDB_RESULT_USER_UNKNOWN, ""
end
```

and of course the backends file with `<domain> <host>` per line.

But I got an error on the proxy

```
pam_unix(dovecot:auth): check pass; user unknown
pam_unix(dovecot:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=dovecot ruser=user@domain rhost=<my-ip>
pam(user@domain,ip,<id>): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (Password mismatch?)
```

What does it mean? I'm not sure - but is it, because I return "NULL" on some of it. When I remove the both attributes `password` and `destuser` it has the same effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pam_authenticate means it's trying a system user lookup, disable pam lookups by commenting out the include for auth-system.conf.ext in 10-auth.conf.

ps: did you get the LUA working? I am trying something similar.

edit - got mine working by adding these fields into the passdb lookup function return fields (NOT userdb lookup function fields):

return dovecot.auth.PASSDB_RESULT_OK, "password=pass proxy=y host=imap.domain.com destuser=remote@user.com pass=anotherpass"

Comment: Partly you're right. By default PAM is enabled in `auth-system.conf.ext`. After removing it, the PAM auth error is gone. But with my script I've got a: `lua(...): No password returned (and no nopassword)`. I'm not sure, if deault_value is realy working. Then I've passed the given values from default_value directly from the LUA script as a response and got the same error, but then it tried with `Cached NULL password access` and then `Authentication failed`.. So Dovecot isn't forwarding the password thru the proxy.